# How can I display eastern arabic numbers (in the output) while using pdfLaTeX?

Tags: tables, pdftex, arabic

My document is mainly in German, but I have to enter the eastern arabic numbers in a table. (Those numbers: `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩`).

Now I found multiple solutions, which are all based on the compiler XeLaTeX (as far as I understood everything correctly). However I can't use this compiler, because I wrote the rest of the document with pdfLaTeX and it would screw up a lot.
I even tried to insert images, instead of the text, in the table, but that didn't work as well (because of the table).

Is there any way to write those numbers with pdfLaTeX in a table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[LAE,T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}
Some arabic numbers

{\fontencoding{LAE}\selectfont1234567890}
\end{document}
```

[image]