Submitting Latex Files to Computer Speech and Language Journal
I am trying to submit my manuscript to Elsevier "Computer Speech and Language" journal. In the Files Attach step, I upload my files as instructed by Elsevier guidelines here: https://www.ariessys.com/wp-content/uploads/EM_PM_LaTeX_Guide.pdf
but whatever I do my final submission file won't include the compiled manuscript instead, it displays the raw logs.

Note: There is no errors on the overleaf projects.
Is there a trick I am missing?
And this is how I upload my files:



Welcome to TeX.SE.

Why are you uploading bst, dtx, and ini files?

@Mico Thank you! Why shouldn't I upload them? but even after removing them I got the same issue, the file is not compiling

By uploading files that are utterly irrelevant, you may not be getting to uplading the ones that are relevent.

show the complete log-file you get, not as screenshot, but the actual file.

dtx and ins are elsevier's source files for their system, they are never read by a document, and submitting them can at best do nothing useful, and at worst will confuse the submission.  Also it looks wrong that your main tex source has type "manuscript" not "latex source"  do you get a tex error? you do not show any relevant part of the log.

@UlrikeFischer Kindly find the actual file here: link

@DavidCarlisle Thank you for the clarification, I uploaded the tex file as a manuscript based on their guidelines I should add the manuscript file as a tex or word file. The complete file you can find here: link

your tex file is faulty. Show the complete preamble.

@UlrikeFischer I added the preamble to a new dummy tex file here: link

do not load the arabtex package it is broken.

@UlrikeFischer but I have Arabic chars in the manuscript

if you have only a few arabic chars try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/576807/2388. If you have lots of arabic switch to lualatex or xelatex if the journal allows it. The arabtex package can not be used.

do not use external links, you have not said if you got an error and have not shown the log. I assume that you did get an error and no pdf was made which is why it is showing the log but you have only shown an image of a small fragment of log, so it's not possible to help

@UlrikeFischer Thank you so much!! The issue is resolved now, the problem were from the arabtex as you mentioned and I used babel instead of it and it worked. Thank you!
